# Navigate to different Page while Dialog is on foreground?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way I can show a Dialog and navigate to another page "behind" the dialog?

I want to achieve the following:

1. Navigate to a TaskPage
2. Show a Dialog with text "Loading..." while doing a specific task
3. Once task completes change text in Dialog to "Task Successful" and a Button "Understood" that pops the Dialog
4. After showing the success in the Dialog, pop the TaskPage but keep showing the "Task Successful" Dialog, until clicking on "Understood"

I'm not sure how to achieve this as the `Navigator.pop` always pops the first layer, which is the Dialog in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can stack it on routes and combine with state management.

```
MaterialApp(
  home: Stack(
    children: [
      Navigator(
        initialRoute: "/",
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          // your routes
        },
      ),
      if (showDialog) YourDialog(),
    ],
  ),
)
```